# VB6 - Items not adding to collection

Tags: vb6

I'm having problems building a collection of data.  The problem code is as follows:

```
    'Basic defitions are as follows:
     Private mCol As Collection
     Dim mcnn As ADODB.Connection
     Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

     Dim uCustomClass As CustomClass
     On Error GoTo 0
     'set Find to false to catch any errors
     Find = False
     'checks for an active connection and then..
     Set mCol = Nothing
     Set mCol = New Collection
     With mrs
     .Open AN_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT , mcnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
     While Not .EOF
        Set uCustomClass = New CustomClass
        Set uCustomClass.Connection = mcnn
        uCustomClass.CustomerName = NullToEquiv(.Fields("customer_name").Value,NULL_STRING)
        uCustomClass.NumberOfOrders = NullToEquiv(.Fields("num_of_orders").Value, NULL_LONG)
        uCustomClass.FavoriteColour = NullToEquiv(.Fields("favorite_colour").Value, NULL_STRING)

        'Cache orginal values in case the keys change
        uCustomClass.CacheOriginalValues
        'add to collection
        mCol.Add uCustomClass
        .MoveNext
    Wend
```

Now the result of this in run time is that the uCustomClass tree structure looks like:

```
    -uCustomClass
       +connection
        count
       + mcnn
       -mCol
          +Item1
          +Item2
          +Item3      
       +mrs
        mvarChangedCount
       +NewEnum
```

It's all good bar I'm not getting Item1, Item2 and Item3 directly under the uCustomClass but only in mCol. I've what appears to be the exact same code running elsewhere for a different custom class and I'm getting what I want e.g.

```
    -uCustomClassThatWorks
        +connection
         count
        + mcnn
        -mCol
           +Item1
           +Item2
           +Item3      
        +mrs
        mvarChangedCount
        +NewEnum
        +Item1
        +Item2
        +Item3
```

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how `uCustomClass` would ever get those items added.  Is there some missing code or something?

One point worth making is that collections can't have the same keys more than once, which would explain why they are able to be added in one area, but not able to be added again.  There might be something that is even trimming strings or something that would aggravate the situation.  So just make sure your keys are unique.